# 'request_cache=true' in GET request to elasticsearch doesn't create a cache

Tags: node.js, caching, elasticsearch

I have a query which takes a long time to process. Therefore, I want to get the cached result from elasticsearch.

What I found out is, that I have to:

- [pass `size=0` to get the cached results](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html#_enabling_caching_per_request)
- **OR** pass `request_cache=true` in the query

My example GET looks like this:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/documentrevisions/_search?request_cache=true' -d '{"size": 10, "query": { }}'
```

I also found this [GitHub PR](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/19472) where they talk exactly about this issue.

> But, when I am setting the `size` to greater than 0, elasticsearch
>   isn't creating a cache, even when I am passing `request_cache=true` in
>   the query.

Is this a bug? Or how can I make sure that I just get a certain amount of results back but still be able to cache those?

*I am using the elastic JS library for NodeJS.*

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it prevents you from filling up the cache with (huge) result sets by default. The cache is (by default) there to avoid iops/additional work for recurring empty result sets.

If you have a lot of requests with results in size 0 arrays, the cache can play out its full potential.

If you know what you are doing, add `request_cache=true` to your queries to also save time for recurring non-empty result sets.